# Is it possible to define the marker size (length/height of a rectangle)

Tags: matlab, size, scatter-plot, marker

I want a rectangle marker. The size (length and width) I want to define
The code is following.

```
 clc
    clear all
    coordinate_x= linspace(0,100,10);
    coordinate_y= rand(size(coordinate_x));
    value=rand(size(coordinate_x));
    colorbar('location','Manual', 'position', [0.93 0.1 0.02 0.81]);
    x = coordinate_x
    y = coordinate_y
    a=13%markersize
    c = value
    axes_definition=gca
    fig = gcf %figure handling
    test=scatter(x,y,a,c,'filled')
    colorbar;
```